# which io scheduler is recommended when use the blk_mq block layer with oracle database?

Tags: linux, kernel, linux-kernel, io, oracle-database

I have oracle Linux 6.10 with 4.1.12 kernel. I have recently moved from the legacy block to the blk_mq block. But all SCSI devices have show io scheduler is none. I have researched but I didn't find any documentation for which io scheduler suggested the blk_mq with oracle database. Is there anybody who can use the IO scheduler with blk_mq for the oracle database?